# Establishing the location of a photo in Fisherton-De-La-Mere

Tags: photo-identification, wiltshire

My mother provided me with this photo of my late dad riding a bicycle:

[image: Dad on Bicycle]

It was understood that he was most likely in the centre of Fisherton-De-La-Mere. So I decided on a hunch to use Google Maps and have a look a street view and came up with [this](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.1456653,-2.0010835,3a,50.4y,76.86h,84.07t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sjGOE9myvgI1Uuej-mAE8QA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656):

[image: Google Maps]

It kind of looks similar to me. The flight of steps appears to be there behind that house and I assume that the church could be up there, behind the trees. The gravel area is there too.

So my hunch is that I might have stumbled on the location of the photo. Are there are other resources available that we can use to establish an approximate location for this photo?

Comment: @Charlie Now that i look again. I think you can actually make out a bit of the Church in the trees on the left, just like the same facade in the Google Maps photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The house has been extended since the photo was taken but I would say that you can be confident that this is the same place. The house has the same number of windows, chimney is in the same position, and even the telephone wire is still there.